# How to prove the outcome of both segment of code are equal?

Tags: algorithms, induction, recursive-algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

The main thing that I want to prove is that the outcome of both segments of code is the same.

Below is the code:

Segment A:

```
int A (int x, int y) {
  if (y==0) return x;
  return A(y, x % y);
}
```

Segment B:

```
int B (int x, int y) {
   while (y!=0) {
      int t = y;
      y = x % y;
      x = t;
   }
   return x;
}
```

$$%code from https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEGBo.png$$

Is it possible to prove equivalence using induction? If possible what would be the steps to proof A=B?

Comment: I half work for half way already which in the inductive case, let k=number of iterations.recursions. Consider the case k=n+1. For each iteration of segment A and each recursion in segment B until k=n+1 iterations and recursion, i have wrote result of x and y. Then i found that in each recursion in segment A and iterations in segment B, the outcome are the same. Finally can i said that the final outcome of return x also will be same if y==0 in segment A and B?

Comment: Could you please type those code snippets _into_ your question instead of just linking to an image? (If you indent each line by 4 spaces or more, the site will preserve your formatting). It is relatively little work to make your question a lot more accessible, and typing everything in at least once has a good chance of giving you a better feeling for what is actually happening anyway.

Comment: *What* returns the segment B? No **return** instruction.

Comment: To establish that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent, the easiest way is probably to establish that both implement the $GCD$ function.  In (A) this is done using induction, in (B) it is done using loop invariant.  Also you have to establish termination; which is rather easy since $y$ is always decreasing by at least 1.  This website is not for giving lectures but for answering questions, so no one is going to teach you how to do this from square one.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/77837/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2357013/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 0):

> What would the inductive case look like?

Assume

$$\forall z ~:~ z < y \implies A(x, z) = B(x, z)$$
$$x = my + z $$
$$0 \le z < y$$

Prove

$$A(x, y) = B(x, y)$$

This is strong induction.